# Binary tree searching class

Tags: python, class, tree

There is an example about binary tree class.

First I define the class Tree.

```
>>> class Tree(object):
>>>     def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
>>>         self.data = data
>>>         self.left = left
>>>         self.right = right
>>>     def inorder(self):
>>>         if self.left:
>>>             for x in self.left.inorder():
>>>                 yield x
>>>             yield self
>>>         if self.right:
>>>             for x in self.right.inorder():
>>>                 yield x
>>>     def __iter__(self):
>>>         return self.inorder()
>>>     def __repr__(self, level=0, indent="     "):
>>>         s = level*indent + `self.data`
>>>         if self.left:
>>>             s = s + "\n" + self.left.__repr__(level+1, indent) # *** Right this point ***
>>>         if self.right:
>>>             s = s + "\n" + self.right.__repr__(level+1, indent)
>>>         return s
```

And then define the function "tree"

```
>>> def tree(List):
>>>     n = len(List)
>>>     if n == 0:
>>>         return None
>>>     i = n / 2
>>>     return Tree(List[i], tree(List[:i]), tree(List[i+1:]))
```

Finally print the binary tree

```
>>> t = tree('abcdef')
>>> print t
```

And result comes out like below.

```
'd'
     'b'
          'a'
          'c'
     'f'
          'e'
```

And the question is why not inserting "self" into **repr** method where i indicate.

self.left is the instance so that it can be possible not to put 'self' into _*repr*_method?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`self.left` is *another* instance of the `Tree` class.

Each element in the tree has two 'child' nodes, `self.left` and `self.right` and the `__repr__` merely delegates printing of those nodes directly to the nodes themselves, with a configurable indentation.

*Normally*, you'd call `repr(self.left)`, and Python in turn will call `self.left.__repr__()`, but that doesn't give you the option of passing in the indentation level; so this code calls `self.left.__repr__()` directly instead.